# Repeating texture of the PlaneGeometry

Tags: three.js

The way of reproduction of the texture, independent of the extent of object is necessary to me. If, for example, to do:

```
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 400, 400, 10, 10 );

    var Texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/texture.png' );
    Texture.wrapS = Texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    Texture.repeat.set( 2, 1 );     

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: Texture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.set(-400,0,0);
    scene.add( mesh );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry.clone(), material.clone() );
    mesh.scale.x = 2;
    mesh.position.set(400,0,0);
    scene.add( mesh );
```

[result here](http://linkme.ufanet.ru/images/c89a1c9bd75931093fd045559336d886.png)

How to redefine texture to receive the following result?
[here](http://linkme.ufanet.ru/images/a30cf8dd31c72f501a327b52adc27dfb.png)

Comment: See if you can get the result you want by cloning the texture, too, and assigning it to the cloned material. Then adjust the new texture's repeat setting. If that does not work, can you provide a live example?

Comment: Ah. Texture.repeat.set( 2, 1 );  
I for some reason thought and was sure that here only integers are applied. Thanks.